# Why the returned array is always empty in POST request in php?

Tags: php, html

Why the returned array is always empty when I send POST request: Array( )?

check.php:

```
<?php
   print_r($_POST);
?>
```

```
<form action="check.php" method="post">
     <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Emale" class="form-control">
     <textarea name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
     <br>
     <button type="submit" name="send" class="btn btn-success">Send</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Your `HTML` code works as intended and produces the correct `$_POST` array. This means you have another error somewhere that doesn't allow you to read the $_POST correct. E.g. you have a redirect, or you strip headers. Is that the whole content of `check.php` or is there something else? Does it include or is included by other files?

Comment: This is all that is in the file check.php

Answer (score 0):

there are a lot of reasons for this issue

1- a prepend file that could change the `$_POST` content

2- rewrite rule in the HTTP server

3- PHP-FPM query parameter

4- in rare cases WAF firewall

try to check every part of this list

I hope it's helpful